# Internet explorer fails to display local image

Tags: file, internet-explorer, local

I've created a bitmap image in C# and want to display this on a webpage on the local machine (so I can print it easily). The problem is, the Internet Explorer 9 does not display the image, it shows the "broken image" icon instead. Firefox has no problems with the image. I'm using Win7, 64 bit.

In order to narrow down the problem, I tried to just drag (from the file explorer) and drop the image file onto an empty browser window. Same thing: Firefox shows it, IE9 doesn't.
It gets even more weird: If I upload the file somewhere (see http://www.diebreuerei.de/Barcode.bmp), the IE9 does display it, it only doesn't if the file is stored locally.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? You can view in Developer Tools (F12)

Comment: Your bitmap file cannot be opened in PhotoShop either. This probably means your bitmap file is being generated in the wrong encoding. When the file is transfered from the web server, it may  be including headers which allow the image to show up correctly, while locally this process doesn't happen. Try generating the bitmap with a UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers, guys.
@Shannon: Nope, the console showed no errors.
@Michael: The Bitmap was directly created in C#, I dunno how to encode it in UTF-8.

But I got a solution: I just save my bitmap in PNG format and the IE9 is happy to display it. So I kinda lost interest in BMP :)

See ya,
Hannes

Comment: Note:  JPG files don't display in IE version 11 either. :-(